# Add prominent Date labels to titles

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Would it be possible to add date labels to titles?  Links to obsolete information keeps showing up in duckduckgo.com searches. There is a lot of valuable data in many topics.  Among the useless questions are those involving companies like ATI, which was taken over by AMD, so link-rot prevails. If date-posted were to accompany the title, such now-useless answers could be more-easily skipped.

Comment: Why not ask DuckDuckGo to display the date? Other search engines manage it, as Stack a Overflow pages are marked up with standardised metadata.

Comment: Google, StartPage and Bing show the dates normally. So it seems it's DuckDuckGo that's at fault here. I also tried Yahoo and...it's super bad - it barely even showed relevant results when I made the same search as the other three search engines. On top of that it *didn't* show dates for the main result [but it did for links within the result](https://i.imgur.com/wjksB5M.png).

Answer (score 13):

The date asked has always been in the user card at the bottom right of the question and is now directly underneath the title itself.

I don't think it needs to be added anywhere else.